# Inserting a Space Before and Italicized Word

Tags: vba, insert, find, ms-word

I have a document in Word which contains hundreds of the Italicized words that have no space in between themselves and the previous word.

For example:

The quick*brown* fox jumps over the lazy*dog*.

The result I am looking for is:

The quick *brown* fox jumps over the lazy *dog*.

I've been trying to construct a macro using the Find and replace and `.InsertBefore` to solve this issue for me but with no success.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub FindItalics()

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute

InsertBefore

End Sub

Sub InsertBefore()
    With Selection
    .InsertBefore " "
    End With
End Sub
```

I have found that this works and does what I require, however it only does it for the first italicized word in the document and will not continue throughout the rest of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sub FindItalics()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection.Range

    With rng.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .Font.Italic = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Forward = True

        While .Execute
            'Note: 'rng' is now the range containing the matched content
            rng.InsertBefore " "
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this without VBA:

In Word's Find/Replace turn on search with wildcards, search for Format, Font..., Italic and search for the pattern *`(*>)`*.

The `*` means find anything,
the `>` means find to the end of the word, and
the `()` parentheses will create a autonumbered group when the pattern is matched.

In the Replace box, don't change the format and Replace with text: `<space>\1` to insert a space followed by group #1.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I have just tried this and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @UserAtlas; I amended the answer --- give it another try.